# "typename qualified-id" referring to a type in a non-type parameter-declaration

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

> ### 14.1 [temp.param], paragraph 2
>
> ... `typename` followed by an *unqualified-id* names a template type parameter. **`typename` followed by a *qualified-id* denotes the type in a non-type parameter-declaration**...

I'm a bit confused about the meaning of the bold text. Specifically, `typename` can occur in two different contexts (*type-specifier* or *template-parameter*), but which one does this refer to?

- For the former case, I considered:

  ```
  struct A {
      struct X { };
      int X;
  };
  struct B {
      struct X { };
  };
  template<class T> void f(T t) {
      typename T::X x;    // T can be A or B
  }
  ```

  However, neither `A::X` nor `B::X` is a non-type *parameter-declaration* (they are *member-declaration*s).
- For the latter case, I'm not sure why that's necessary. Why not directly write down its type with *qualified-id*? Is parameterization necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is about

```
struct S { typedef int X; };
template <typename T, typename T::X> void f() { }
int main() { f<S, 1>(); }
```

Here, `typename T` means `T` is a named template type parameter, but `typename T::X` is the type of an unnamed non-type template parameter.

*type-parameter* is the syntax used for template type parameters, *parameter-declaration* is the syntax used for template non-type parameters.

`typename T` cannot be parsed as a *typename-specifier* in a *parameter-declaration*, as it lacks the *nested-name-specifier*, so it must be a *type-parameter*.

`typename T::X` cannot be parsed as a *type-parameter*, as it only allows a single identifier after the `typename` keyword, so it must be a *parameter-declaration*.

I think there's no ambiguity, but the text clarifies how differently these two *template-parameter*s are parsed.

Comment: "parameter-declaration" still haunts me... Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @Il-seobBae I don't understand which part you're not getting, can you be more specific in your question? Both `typename T` and `typename T::X` are declarations of template parameters, if that helps.

Comment: template-parameter can be type-parameter or parameter-declaration, and clearly both `typename T` and `typename T::X` are type-parameters. The bold text requires that the type need to be in parameter-declaration, and I'm not sure which syntactic unit in your code is parameter-declaration.

Comment: @Il-seobBae I understand your question now, and initially made a wrong edit to cover that. Will try to edit better.

Comment: Take your time! I'm really grateful just by getting attention.

Comment: You're right. `typename T::X` must be _parameter-declaration_. I think the standard clarified it by saying "in a non-type **parameter-declaration**". Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

"**typename followed by an unqualified-id names a template type parameter. typename followed by a qualified-id denotes the type in a non-type131 parameter-declaration**"

example : compiled using g++ -std=c++2a

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace X {
    struct S {
    int i;
    };
}
```

typename X::S  is qualified id which declares non-type template parameter

T is un-qualified id names a template parameter

```
template< typename X::S &N,typename T>
    void fun(T a) {
    cout << "non-type paramet N.i = " << N.i << endl;
    cout << "type paramet a = " << a << endl;
}

X::S  x{ i:10 };
int main() {
    fun<x,int >(5);
}
```